# Reformatting NTFS file system

Tags: hard-drive, ssd, ntfs

My computer crashed a while ago and the problem was that it was a Lenovo with Rapid Drive Technology, where I had SSD and HDD separate drives but there was only one big partition probably spanning over SSD and HDD. Therefore I had plenty of space but was able start up my PC in 10-20 seconds.

My HDD was physically damaged and I could rescue a lot of data with PhotoRec. Problem is that with PhotoRec I lose folders and file names.

I was examining the NTFS image, I have created of my healthy SSD and found out that it spans outside of the SSD! So the file system in the image of my SSD has references outside of the storage capacity of the device.

So if I can manipulate the NTFS on a low level and shrink it to the size of SSD, then I can maybe get the file system back without the data from HDD. Do you know any tools to use for low level NTFS manipulation/altering?

Thanks a lot!

Comment: Sounds like a call to Lenovo is in order!

Comment: are you sure that there's a ntfs partition on the ssd?

Comment: It seems strange you had a SSD and it still took 20 seconds to boot.

Comment: Ad Gotschi: Yes I am sure, there is the partition, the problem is that it extends beyond the SSD. This I can see.
Ad Ramhound: well 20 min max, sometimes shorter :)
Ad mdpc: Lenovo did replace the broken HDD, but I still have the image of SSD.